# Ajax Tabs Fade Effect Problem - jQuery Tools

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-tabs

I am unable to get the Ajax Tabs with a fade effect to work when using the jQuery Tools library. It only shows the effect for the first item called by the ajax, but nothing else.

You may see the test URL at  **www.excellenthost(dot)com/beta/test.php** or see the code below:

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("ul.features-tabs").tabs(".features-panes > div.features", {
        effect: 'fade',
        history: true,
        onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
            loaddetails(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("id"));
    function loaddetails(type) { var query = "details=" + type; 
    $.post("shared/details.php", query , function( data ) {
     $(".features").html(data); return false;}); return false;
   }; }});
   });
</script>
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="hostingFeatures-shadow"></div>
      <div class="hostingFeatures-bg">
      <div class="wrap"> 
          <ul class="features-tabs">
            <li><a id="core" href="#core">Core</a></li>
            <li><a id="email" href="#email">Email</a></li>

        </ul>

        <div class="features-panes">
            <ul class="packages-bar">
                <li class="features-title">&nbsp;</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
            </ul>

            <!-- First Slide -->
      <div class="features">
        </div>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

AJAX Content:
shared/details.php

```
<ul class="features-list"> 
 <? if($_POST['details']=='core'){ ?>
            <li class="features-name">Premium Disk Space</li>
                        <li>1000MB</li>
                        <li>2500MB</li>
                        <li>3500MB</li>
 <? } if($_POST['details']=='email'){ ?>
                       <li class="features-name">Email Accounts</li>
                        <li>35</li>
                        <li>45</li>
                        <li>65</li>
<? } ?>
</ul>
```

As you can see from the sample, nothing loads when 'email' tab is clicked. When I do a debug alert(data);, the Ajax data appears properly, so there is no problem with grabbing the correct data. It is only a problem of getting it posted on the actual main page

Can someone please assist?
Brian

Comment: If you end up using one of the answers, you really should mark that answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

If you really want the 'fade' effect, you can do this:

```
<ul class="features-tabs">
  <li><a href="/hosting/shared/details.php?details=core">Core</a></li>
  <li><a href="/hosting/shared/details.php?details=email">Email</a></li>
</ul>
(...)
<div class="features">
    <!-- Two divs to keep the content panes separated -->
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

And use this Javascript:

```
$("ul.features-tabs").tabs("div.features > div", {
  effect: 'fade',
  onBeforeClick: function(event, i) {
    var pane = this.getPanes().eq(i);
    if (pane.is(":empty")) {
      pane.load(this.getTabs().eq(i).attr("href"));
    }
  }
});
```

That should work!

Comment: But I wanted a "fade" effect, is that not possible? I followed the documentation at http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/ajax-noeffect.htm

Comment: I tried that, but still no 'fade' effect! The code you provided was in the documentation and it does NOT work. Which is why I need help to figure out why it is not working for my page.

Comment: I tried it right here: http://junk.dk/files/so/excellenthost/test.html and it basically works. The first time a pane is loaded however, the fadein happens before the content is loaded, so you don't see the effect.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the jQuery Tools Tabs solution isn't very well suited for this, so I've made a custom script for you:

[**DEMO**](http://junk.dk/files/so/excellenthost/testbetter.html)

```
$("ul.features-tabs").find('a').each(function(i) {

  $(this).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var clickedPane = $("div.features > div").eq(i);
    if (clickedPane.is(':visible')) return;

    $(this).closest('ul').find('a').removeClass('current').end().end().addClass('current');

    if (clickedPane.hasClass('contentLoaded') || clickedPane.hasClass('contentLoading')) {
      clickedPane.siblings().fadeOut( function(){ clickedPane.fadeIn(); } );
    } else {
      clickedPane.addClass('contentLoading').load($(this).attr("href"),function(){
        $(this).removeClass('contentLoading').addClass('contentLoaded').siblings().fadeOut( function(){ clickedPane.fadeIn(); } );
      });
    }
  });

  // Load & show the initial tabbed pane
  if (i==0) $(this).click();
});
```

It does away with jQuery Tools entirely and it does all the fading and Ajax loading you need.

To make it work, you need to change the HTML a little:

```
<div class="hostingFeatures-bg">
  <div class="wrap">

    <ul class="features-tabs">
      <li><a href="/hosting/shared/details.php?details=core">Core</a></li>
      <li><a href="/hosting/shared/details.php?details=email">Email</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="features-panes">
      <ul class="packages-bar">
        <li class="features-title">&nbsp;</li>
        <li>ER-1</li>
        <li>ER-2</li>
        <li>ER-3</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="features">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And make one addition to your CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .features > div { display: none; }
</style>
```